# Gradle sync: Connection to the Internet denied

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I'm trying to sync a Gradle project, but the next Error emerges:

```
Error: Connection to the Internet denied.
```

It also says to check this [page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/project-sync-issues-android-studio) but the workaround didn't make it.

Answer (score 3):

Its a issue by window firewall, please turn off your window firewall.

Comment: In my case my office security software was blocking Java.exe. Had to contact the security team to by pass the block, after that studio was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to the company I work for having rigorous firewall and port blocking for security reasons.
Check if you have any firewall software in place and change the settings in this if you are able to to enable grandle to download the packages you need.

The Android documentation also offers some tips if you are required to use a proxy. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html